# OpenGL delete lines

Tags: c, opengl

I want draw lines and then I click the line and delete it. How can I find the line that I wanted by using mouse? Can an one help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your question has nothing to do with OpenGL you know. You'll have to keep a collection of lines around, get your mouse input somehow (depends on what you're using), figure out whether the mouse position during a click was within an existing line (with some margin of error), and then remove that from the collection.

Comment: gluPickMatrix() using this to pick the line?

Comment: What I want is using mouse draw lines and click one of them and then delete it!~~

Comment: No. Like I said, this has absolutely nothing to do with OpenGL. There is nothing in OpenGL that does this, or even helps doing this. It seems you are confused as to what OpenGL is and does, I'd suggest you to do some reading on it and come back later once you've done so.

Comment: well I just want to say. OpenGL can do it, just you do not know. But thank you for your respond. I hope I can find it by myself

Comment: @user2099155 No. OpenGL is a low level rendering API. Exactly that. None of the things you have to do to get this working (retrieving mouse clicks/coordinated, checking to see whether the mouse click was on a line, removing that line) is anything related to OpenGL.